# Make the right GET request

Tags: angular, api, http

I'm certain not making the right get request in Angular to get a String from a Java api or I'm not calling the get function in the right way in the .subscribe() method, here is my service.ts I got the issue with the method buscarPorId():

```
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { catchError, Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { IInformeCliente } from '../components/client-form/IInformeCliente';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ServicioDeFormularioService {


  private baseURL: string = 'http://localhost:8093/api';
  id: string = '';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }


  //metodo para enviar al backend los datos para crear el formulario de cliente
  enviarFormularioCliente(formularioCliente: IInformeCliente): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.post(`${this.baseURL + '/enviarFormularioCliente'}`, formularioCliente).pipe(
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }


  buscarPorId(): Observable<string> {
   return  this.httpClient.get<string>(`${this.baseURL + '/buscaId'}`).pipe(
    catchError(this.handleError)
   )
  };
```

then I call the method from the component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { IInformeCliente } from '../../client-form/IInformeCliente';
import { ServicioDeFormularioService } from 'src/app/services/servicio-de-formulario.service';
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-formulario-cliente',
  templateUrl: './formulario-cliente.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./formulario-cliente.component.scss']
})
export class FormularioClienteComponent {

  pipe = new DatePipe('es-ES');
  fechaComienzo1 = null;
  fechaFinal1 = null;
  rutaInforme: string = 'http://localhost:8093/api/recibirPDF/';

  formularioCliente: IInformeCliente = {
    id: 0,
    descripcion: '',
    resolucion: '',
    fechaComienzo: '',
    fechaFinal: '',
    tecnico: '',
    minutosEmpleados: 0,
  }

  clientForm = this.fb.group({
    id: [null, Validators.required],
    descripcion: [null, Validators.required],
    resolucion: [null, Validators.required],
    fechaComienzo: [null, Validators.required],
    fechaFinal: [null, Validators.required],
    tecnico: [null, Validators.required],
    tiempo: [null, Validators.required],
  });


  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private router: Router, private servicio: ServicioDeFormularioService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  onSubmit(): void {

    this.fechaComienzo1 = this.pipe.transform(this.clientForm.value.fechaComienzo, 'dd/MM/yyyy');
    this.fechaFinal1 = this.pipe.transform(this.clientForm.value.fechaFinal, 'dd/MM/yyyy');

    this.formularioCliente.id = Number(this.clientForm.value.id);
    this.formularioCliente.descripcion = String(this.clientForm.value.descripcion);
    this.formularioCliente.resolucion = String(this.clientForm.value.resolucion);
    this.formularioCliente.fechaComienzo = String(this.fechaComienzo1);
    this.formularioCliente.fechaFinal = String(this.fechaFinal1);
    this.formularioCliente.tecnico = String(this.clientForm.value.tecnico);
    this.formularioCliente.minutosEmpleados = Number(this.clientForm.value.tiempo);

    console.log(this.formularioCliente);


    //TODO gestionar la respuesta del backend para mostar el PDF informe del cliente dentro de los
    //argumentos de subscribe()
    this.servicio.enviarFormularioCliente(this.formularioCliente).subscribe();

    this.servicio.buscarPorId().subscribe(
      (v) => this.rutaInforme + v
    );

    window.open(this.rutaInforme);
    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
    this.clientForm.reset();

    /** **/
  }
  navegarVolverHome(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
  }
  resetForm(): void {

  }
}
```

I've readed the rxjs documentation but I do not reach to understand how I need to make the call, It suppose that I receive from the api a String that is a url I need to open

Answer (score 0):

Since you expect a string here and not an object, you need to change the response type.

```
buscarPorId(): Observable<string> {
   return  this.httpClient.get<string>(`${this.baseURL + '/buscaId'}`, { responseType: 'text' }).pipe(
    catchError(this.handleError)
   )
  };
```